# Is it called a doorway even if there's no door?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

Example:

> He moved to the **doorway** to the family room and peeked in.

Is 'doorway' used even if there's no door but just an opening into another room? Or would native speakers use another word for that?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318860/term-for-a-doorway-without-a-door  and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16371/whats-a-doorway-that-doesnt-have-a-door-called

Comment: doorway of the family room here.

Answer (score 0):

If there was once a door there but it has been removed, you can call it a doorway. If there was never a doorway and you don't want to specify the actual structure, it would be better to call it an entrance.

---

Note that *moved* is a very weak word to use in creative writing. In what way was he moving? tiptoeing, striding, sneaking?

Comment: Plain words have a place in creative writing. Big words are best used sparingly, lest you end up with unreadable purple prose.

Answer (score 0):

"doorway" is the correct word, whether there was ever a door there or not.

I did an image search for "doorway" and roughly half the images were of structures that had never had any door -- just arches that you can pass through.

Here's two examples:

[image]
[image]